# Exist this word/symbol in Latex

Tags: symbols

How can I represent this word/symbol in Latex??

Symbol:

[image]

I search in [Latex's Symbols](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols) but I don't find it

Thanks

Comment: Warning -> That may be an idiotic question : Do you need this specific symbol or another question mark symbol woul suit you too ?

Comment: Yes, necesito este símbolo específico. Este símbolo es generado por Firefox

Comment: To help anyone searching, it's the Unicode replacement character U+FFFD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a quick hack, you could create the symbol yourself:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\diaquestion}{\ensuremath{\blacklozenge\kern-0.5em{\color{white}\scalebox{0.7}{?}}\kern0.2em}}

\begin{document}

text \diaquestion\ more text

\end{document}
```

[image]